# How can I set the default access rules for new users?

Tags: odoo

I have created a set of rules for accessing my addon by users, everything works, but I can't set the rules when creating a new user. On the settings, the user form, the access parameter for my addon is not set
I tried this
security/addon_security.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <record model="ir.module.category" id="myaddon_groups">
        <field name="name">My Addon</field>
        <field name="description">User access level for My addon</field>
        <field name="sequence">20</field>
    </record>
    <record id="myaddon_user" model="res.groups">
        <field name="name">User</field>
        <field name="category_id" ref="myaddond_groups"/>
    </record>
    <record id="myaddon_editor" model="res.groups">
        <field name="name">Editor</field>
        <field name="category_id" ref="myaddon_groups"/>
        <field name="implied_ids" eval="[(4, ref('myaddon_user'))]"/>
    </record>
    <record id="myaddon_manager" model="res.groups">
        <field name="name">Manager</field>
        <field name="category_id" ref="myaddond_groups"/>
        <field name="implied_ids" eval="[(4, ref('myaddon_user'))]"/>
    </record>
    <record id="base.default_user" model="res.users">
        <field name="groups_id" eval="[(4, ref('myaddon_manager'))]"/>
    </record>
    <record id="base.group_system" model="res.groups">
        <field name="implied_ids" eval="[(4, ref('myaddon.myaddon_manager'))]"/>
    </record>

</odoo>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by myself

```xml
<!-- at the end -->
<record id="base.group_system" model="res.groups">
        <field name="implied_ids" eval="[(4, ref('myaddon.myaddon_user'))]"/>
    </record>
    <record id="base.default_user" model="res.users">
        <field name="groups_id" eval="[(4, ref('myaddon_user'))]"/>
    </record>
```